# Solution for differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Not sure how to attempt this and whether anything should be isolated or rearranged.

> Find the particular solution to the following differential equation,
>
> $$y'+2y=x$$
>
> satisfying the initial condition $y(0)=1$.

Comment: Do you know of the integrating factor method?

Comment: Have you learnt anything about differential equations ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to **avoid** using the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) method or using [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters):

---

Your ODE is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x-2y$$
Therefore, try substituting the following to obtain a [separable differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx):
$$v=x-2y \implies y=\frac{x-v}{2}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-\frac{dv}{dx}}{2}$$
This gives:
$$\frac{1-\frac{dv}{dx}}{2}=v$$
Rearranging gives the ODE required:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=1-2v$$
Can you separate the variables and integrate? Do not forget to substitute back to obtain $y(x)$ and then apply your initial condition $y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**By trial and error**:

If we take $y=ax$ and plug this in the equation, we have

$$a+2ax=x$$ which hints to set $a=\frac12$, and to add a constant to compensate the independent term. Now with $y=\frac x2+b$,

$$\frac12+x+2b=x$$ so that

$$y=\frac x2-\frac14$$ is a particular solution. Anyway, it doesn't satisfy the initial condition.

Let us now add a new arbitrary term, $z$, and $y=\frac x2-\frac14+z$ yields

$$\frac12+x-\frac12+z'+2z=x$$ or

$$z'+2z=0,$$ with the initial condition $z(0)=\frac54$.

We can rewrite

$$\frac{z'}z=-2$$ and integrate from $0$ to get

$$\log z-\log\frac54=-2x$$ or

$$z=\frac54e^{-2x}.$$

Finally,

$$y=\frac x2-\frac14+\frac54e^{-2x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There is an (in my opinion elegant) solution to this. Multiply both sides with a function $\mu(x)$, then you get $\mu(x)y' + 2\mu(x)y = x\mu(x)$. Now you got to pick $\mu(x)$ so that $2\mu(x) = \mu(x)'$. This way the left side can be simplified to $(\mu(x)y)'$. Back to $2\mu(x) = \mu(x)'$. This is a simple differential equation, you get $2 = \frac{\mu(x)'}{\mu(x)}$. Integrate both parts to x and you find $\ln(\mu(x)) = 2x$ or $\mu(x) = e^{2x}$. Back to the original equation: $(\mu(x)y)' = x\mu(x)$. This gives $(e^{2x}y)' = xe^{2x}$. Integrate both sides to x and you get $e^{2x}y = \int xe^{2x}dx$. Integration of the right side: $\int xe^{2x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int xde^{2x} = \frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}x-\int e^{2x}dx) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}x-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+c) = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x-\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{2}c$. Bringing this back gives $e^{2x}y = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x-\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{2}c$ so $y = \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{c}{2e^{2x}}$. Now you can find the value for c, simply fill in $x = 0$, then $y = 1$: $1 = \frac{1}{2}0-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{c}{2e^{0}} = \frac{-1}{4} + \frac{c}{2}$. This gives $c = \frac{5}{2}$. Filling in c back leads to $y = \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{4e^{2x}}$.

Comment: Note: you should technically take the absolute value of $\mu(x)$ in the $\ln$, so $\ln|\mu(x)|)$. However, since $\mu(x) = e^{2x}$ and this is always $\geq 0$, you can drop the absolute value

Answer (score 0):

I attacked the problem using the Laplace transform, hope you know how to use it.

You have the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}+2y=x $$

Doing the Laplace transform we have:
$$sY(s)-1+2Y(s)=\frac{1}{s^{2}} $$

Rearranging the equation:

$$ Y(s)=\frac{1+s^{2}}{s^{2}(2+s)} $$

Decomposing into simple fractions:
$$ Y(s)=\frac{1/2}{s^{2}}+\frac{5/4}{s+2}-\frac{1/4}{s} $$

Doing the inverse laplace transform we have y(x):

$$ y(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{4}e^{-2x}-\frac{1}{4} $$